# Remove part of lines in sides of rectange in android

Tags: android, canvas, android-drawable

I want to draw a background rectangle for a view in Android . Here is my code

```
rectBox= new RectF(0, 0, 200,
        200);
Paint paint= new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectBox, 0, 0, paint);
```

I am getting the output

[image]

I want this output. I want to remove the part of segments in the edges of a rectangle

[image]

Please give an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just draw lines (or rectangles) with background color over that segments.

**Update**
Draw just necessary parts using `drawLine()` and `drawArc()`.

Comment: My background color is dynamic , so we do not know the color of view,

Comment: In android ? do we have an option to remove drawn line?

Comment: I mean draw only "non transparent" parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw transparent lines over the necessary places.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
canvas.drawLine(0, 8, 0, 15, paint);
canvas.drawLine(8, 0, 15, 0, paint);
canvas.drawLine(8, 8, 8, 15, paint);
canvas.drawLine(15, 8, 15, 15, paint);
```

Comment: No, i do not want white color, I want to remove the portion of a line .I want to see the background color of screen , But my screen back ground color is dynamic image,

Comment: I edited the answer. You can draw transparent lines.

Comment: Tried this,  color of the rectangle is seen

Comment: You can try drawing multiple line segments with the gaps. And arcs connecting perpendicular line segments.

Comment: I think this is my last option, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for the round corner but here what i'm doned in one of my project

```
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

        // Full left band
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, rect.left, getHeight(), rectPaint);

        // Full right band
        canvas.drawRect(rect.right, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), rectPaint);

        // Partial top band
        canvas.drawRect(rect.left, 0, rect.right, rect.top, rectPaint);

        // Partial bottom band
        canvas.drawRect(rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.right, getHeight(), rectPaint);

        // Top lines
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.left - strokeWidth, rect.top - strokeWidth,
                rect.left + cornerLength, rect.top,
                borderPaint
        );
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.right - cornerLength, rect.top - strokeWidth,
                rect.right + strokeWidth, rect.top,
                borderPaint
        );

        // Bottom lines
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.left - strokeWidth, rect.bottom,
                rect.left + cornerLength, rect.bottom + strokeWidth,
                borderPaint
        );
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.right - cornerLength, rect.bottom,
                rect.right + strokeWidth, rect.bottom + strokeWidth,
                borderPaint
        );

        // Left lines
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.left - strokeWidth, rect.top - strokeWidth,
                rect.left, rect.top + cornerLength,
                borderPaint
        );
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.left - strokeWidth, rect.bottom - cornerLength,
                rect.left, rect.bottom + strokeWidth,
                borderPaint
        );

        // Right lines
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.right, rect.top - strokeWidth,
                rect.right + strokeWidth, rect.top + cornerLength,
                borderPaint
        );
        canvas.drawRect(
                rect.right, rect.bottom - cornerLength,
                rect.right + strokeWidth, rect.bottom + strokeWidth,
                borderPaint
        );

}
```